# Single word: Something that is experienced by more than one person/party

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, vocabulary

Similar to how 'multilateral' means contributed to by multiple people/countries,  I want a word that would describe something experienced by all parties in an event.

Example:

> So if economic prosperity was being experienced by all countries, it's
>   a ________ progress.

Comment: It's unclear from your question why "multilateral" doesn't work. The example sentence, minus the "a," seems fine with "multilateral." (Unless the sentence was not meant to be an example, which is also unclear).

Comment: There is also "mutual".

Comment: It could also be as simple as “*... it’s **shared** progress*”

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context. If you're talking specifically about something experienced by *all countries,* as in your example, you could say the progress was [global](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/global) or [universal:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/universal)

> **global**, adjective
>
> 1. pertaining to the whole world; worldwide; universal:
>
> **universal,** adjective
>
> 1. of, relating to, or characteristic of all or the whole
> 2. applicable everywhere or in all cases
> 3. affecting, concerning, or involving all
> 4. used or understood by all

Global or universal would also work in a more general context (as would **general** itself). Other words might be appropriate for specific contexts. For example

> the orchestra played to an [enraptured](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enrapture) audience

And as @KatherineLockwood points out, **multilateral** would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [collective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collective) [MWD]

> shared or done by a group of people: involving all members of a group

or [social](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/social) [MWD]

> of or relating to people or society in general

Answer (score 1):

The word ***inclusive*** implies all the concerned parties are included.

> So if economic prosperity was being experienced by all countries, it's
>   ***inclusive*** progress.

ODO:

> **[inclusive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inclusive)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.3** Not excluding any section of society or any party involved in something:
>   ‘only an inclusive peace process will end the conflict’
>
> ‘Dr Madden pointed out that the University of Pittsburgh Medical
>   Centre was a not-for-profit organisation that required its facilities
>   to be socially inclusive.’